# CLR / VectoredExceptionHandler / StackOverflowException / MiniDumpWriteDump

Tags: c#, winapi, clr, native, dump

Only for StackOverflow-exception, I am struggling to create a MiniDump when configuring AddVectoredExceptionHandler from a process that has the CLR loaded.

My handler gets called, the .dmp file gets created but then MiniDumpWriteDump fails.

I have no problem writing the dump for other exceptions, e.g. AccessViolation. If the CLR is not loaded and a StackOverflow-exceptin occurs, then I also get the dump successfully written.

Sample-code is provided on https://github.com/NicolaiNyberg/DbgSvcExtension 
where the CrashHandler dll project configures the handlers and SoexCh.Cs is an example of it being called from C#.

My question is: what happens with respect to unhandled exception handlers once the CLR is loaded that prevents the process from writing a mini-dump in the event of a StackOverflow-exception ?

Comment: There is not enough stack space left to allow MiniDumpWriteDump() to do its job.  Reliable minidump generation requires a "guard process".  Like DebugDiag.

Comment: Thanks Hans. I just read your answer and I realized my answer/solution is an implementation of what you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> Answer/solution: In order for MiniDumpWriteDump to succeed from a smashed stack (StackOverflow-exception), then it should be called from a worker thread that gets signalled from the ExceptionHandler. The CrashHandler has been updated with this implementation.

Comment: Actually, it _really_ should be in a separate watch dog process (like Hans' suggested in his comment). While a separate thread might work for stackoverflow errors, it might not be enough for stat corrupting things (like access violation) that can hose the entire (target/victim) process.